# Owin hosted webapi 2.2. testing controller with mocked service

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, owin, autofac

I have webapi which for testing purposes I am hosting in owin. I have set it up using autofac. now when I am testing I want to inject moq dependencies. which I am not able to so far. I have read the documentation and did bit of research but I am missing something.

here is the testing code.

```
 [Test]
    public void Request_all_airports()
    {
        const int port = 8086;
        AirportCollection moqAirportCollection = new AirportCollection();
        moqAirportCollection.Airports = new List<Airport>{new Airport{IATA = "moq",Name = "moqName"}};

        using (WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://localhost:" + port))
        {
            using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
            {
                var moqObj =  mock.Mock<IAirportService>().Setup(x => x.GetAirports()).Returns(moqAirportCollection);

                var client = new HttpClient {BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:" + port)};
                var response = client.GetAsync("/api/airport/get").Result;
                var body = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var airportCollection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AirportCollection>(body);
            }
        }
    }
```

Please have a look. let me know what I am missing. if you want to look at controller code or any other piece do let me know .

here is code for startup

```
 public class Startup
{
    public static IContainer container { get; set; }

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        var httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
        container = AutofacSetup.Register(httpConfig);
        WebApiConfig.Register(httpConfig);


        appBuilder.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
        appBuilder.UseAutofacWebApi(httpConfig);
        appBuilder.UseWebApi(httpConfig);
    }
}
```

Thanks

I think so I have solved it with help from people. here is my code.

```
var moq = new Mock<IAirportService>();
                moq.Setup(x => x.GetAirports()).Returns(moqAirportCollection);
                newBuilder.RegisterInstance(moq.Object).As<IAirportService>();
                newBuilder.Update(Startup.container);
```

I havnt rebuild the contrain i just updated it. autofac have behavior to use latest registration so it will use mocked on here.

Comment: In your application do you register your dependencies in startup? Can you post the code of your startup and DI setup please?

Comment: @AnishPatel I have posted the code for startup. in startup I am calling a custom class AutofacSetup.Register which is registering all dependencies. let me know if you wan to have a look at this one.

Comment: @AnishPatel please have a look. I have updated the question with possible solution and it is working please have a look and let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there.

In your test you need to register your mock service with your *autofac* container so that dependencies on `IAirportService` are resolved with the mock in the application.

One way to achieve this is override the `Startup` class' `Configuration` method for each test and put your test *DI* in there. I've put some comments below to show changes that can be made:

```
public class Startup
{
    public static IContainer container { get; set; }

    // make this virtual
    public virtual void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        var httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();

        // have this return the ContainerBuilder instead of the container
        var builder = AutofacSetup.Register(httpConfig)
        container = builder.Build();

        WebApiConfig.Register(httpConfig);


        appBuilder.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
        appBuilder.UseAutofacWebApi(httpConfig);
        appBuilder.UseWebApi(httpConfig);
    }
}
```

Then in your test class, derive from the `Startup` class and put your test logic in. Something like this:

```
public class MyTestCase {
        public static Mock<IAirportService> MockObj { get; set; }

        private class TestStartup : Startup {
            public override void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
                var httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();

                // this now returns ContainerBuilder instead of the container
                var builder = AutofacSetup.Register(httpConfig)

                // register your mock, change this to whatever lifetime scope you need
                var moqAirportCollection = new AirportCollection();
                moqAirportCollection.Airports = new List<Airport>{new Airport{IATA = "moq",Name = "moqName"}};
                var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose()
                MockObj = mock.Mock<IAirportService>()
                                           .Setup(x => x.GetAirports())
                                           .Returns(moqAirportCollection);
                var moqObj = MockObj.Object;
                builder.RegisterInstance(moqObj).As<IAirportService>();



                container = builder.Build();

                WebApiConfig.Register(httpConfig);


                appBuilder.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
                appBuilder.UseAutofacWebApi(httpConfig);
                appBuilder.UseWebApi(httpConfig);
            }
        }

        [Test]
        public void Request_all_airports()
        {    
           using (var server = WebApp.Start<Startup>())
           {
               var response = 
                   server.CreateRequest("/api/airport/get")
                         .GetAsync()
                         .Result;

                var body = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AirportCollection>(body);

                // assert something
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think so I am getting close. but this line is not working " builder.Register<IAirportService>(() => moqObj);"  error is about coverting expression

Comment: Sorry mate something is not right. I am getting this error.

Comment: nad is there a reason for writing it like that var " moqObj = MockObj = mock......"

Comment: @haroonlatif Your updated question looks good, I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

A unit test should test a single component. In your case, you are trying to test the `AirportController` through a HTTP query, not the `AirportController` as a standalone component.

The `AirportController` class depends on a `IAirportService` component. In order to test the component without any dependency you created a moq on `IAirportService`. Now you can instantiate a new `AirportController` with this moq and run your test using this instance.

If you have a `AirportController` like this

```
public class AirportController
{
    public AirportController(IAirportService airportService) { /* ... */}
}
```

The `AirportController` test should be like this :

```
[Test]
public void Request_all_airports()
{
    AirportCollection moqAirportCollection = new AirportCollection();
    var moqAirPort = new Airport{ IATA = "moq",Name = "moqName" };
    moqAirportCollection.Airports = new List<Airport>{ moqAirPort };

    using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
    {
        var moqAirportService = mock.Mock<IAirportService>()
                                    .Setup(x => x.GetAirports())
                                    .Returns(moqAirportCollection);
        var testedAirportController = new AirportController(moqAirportService); 

        AirportCollection airportCollection = testedAirportController.Get();

        Assert.AreEquals(1, airportCollection.Length, "Invalid number of airport"); 
        Assert.AreEquals(moqAirPort.Name, airportCollection[0].Name, "Invalid name");
    }
}
```